# How to unit-test BizTalk maps containing e.g. DB functoids?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-mapper

I am exploring the possibilities of unit-testing BizTalk Server 2010 artifacts with MSTest.

So currently I am testing maps (thanks to `TestableMapBase`) and comparing outputs (using `XmlDsigC14NTransform`'s digested output) and all that works fine –*now*– but:

How can I properly unit-test a map containing e.g. a `DatabaseLookupFunctoid` and `DatabaseValueExtractFunctoid`, or perhaps simply a `DateCurrentDateFunctoid`?

Answer (score 0):

I experimented a bit with the [Moles framework](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) and that already allows me to solve the problem with the `DateCurrentDateFunctoid`, since it suffices to deroute `DateTime.Now` for that.

Still, I need to further check its possibilities or alternatives, without just pulling out the big guns like TypeMock or JustMock…